# Postgresql tranform to json

Tags: json, postgresql

I hope someone would be able to help, I am fairly new to PostgreSQL, not to mention json conversions thereof.

Currently I have written a cursor that populates the data from different tables in postgresql into a "temp" table (using json_agg) and then selecting the columns from the temp table to get the result set I need. This works well (for the time being), problem is I cannot find how to show the data the way the client wants.

The temp select that I am running is:

```
SELECT json_agg(tst)
FROM (
    SELECT 
        json_agg(
            json_build_array(
                'policy',policy::json,
                'item',item::json,
                'item_excess',item_excess::json,
                'item_extra',item_extra::json
            )
        ) as tst
    FROM pvt.test_file
    GROUP by policy
)s
```

The output that I get is:

```
[
  [
    [
      "policy",
      [
        {
          "client_unique_reference": "unq1",
          "policy_unique_reference": "pol1",
          "policy_no": "123",
          "policy_account_no": "1221",
          "policy_account_holder": "Mr T ME",
          "policy_account_bank": "mybank",
          "policy_account_branch_name": "branch1",
          "policy_account_branch_code": "1221",
          "policy_account_type": "Current",
          "policy_insurer_policy_no": "",
          "policy_previous_policy_no": "",
          "policy_additional_policy_no": "",
          "policy_status": "Active",
          "policy_insurer": "Insurer1",
          "policy_insurer_underwriter": "",
          "policy_product": "New Product",
          "policy_product_code": "PDT1",
          "policy_product_type": "PDT2",
          "policy_brokerage": "TST BKE",
          "policy_brokerage_region": "Region1",
          "policy_brokerage_vat_no": "1221111",
          "policy_broker_age_fsp_no": "876566",
          "policy_brokerage_branch": "bkr brn",
          "policy_broker": "Dummy data",
          "policy_broker_email": "test@me.com",
          "policy_broker_cell_no": "122333",
          "policy_broker_office_no": "11111",
          "policy_broker_account_executive": "",
          "policy_brokerage_underwriter": "",
          "policy_division": "",
          "policy_type": "new policy",
          "policy_collection_type": "payments",
          "policy_start_date": "2022-02-01",
          "policy_end_date": "2022-02-28",
          "policy_review_date": "2022-11-01",
          "policy_original_inception_date": "2021-11-01",
          "policy_inception_date": "2021-11-01",
          "policy_capture_date": "2021-10-12",
          "policy_cancellation_date": null,
          "policy_cancellation_reason": "",
          "policy_revision_no": 4,
          "policy_endorsement_no": 1,
          "policy_endorsement_processed_date": "2022-02-07",
          "policy_payment_method": "Debit Order",
          "policy_debit_day": "1",
          "policy_activation_date": "2021-10-12",
          "policy_activation_reason": "",
          "policy_reinstatement_date": null,
          "policy_reinstatement_reason": "",
          "policy_reinstatement_type": "",
          "policy_last_endorsement_date": "2022-02-07",
          "policy_vat_rate": 15,
          "policy_underwriter_fee": 0,
          "policy_underwriter_fee_vat": 0,
          "policy_underwriter_fee_prorata": 0,
          "policy_underwriter_fee_prorata_vat": 0,
          "policy_broker_fee": 0,
          "policy_broker_fee_vat": 0,
          "policy_broker_fee_prorata": 0,
          "policy_broker_fee_prorata_vat": 0,
          "policy_administrator_fee": 168.43,
          "policy_administrator_fee_vat": 21.97,
          "policy_administrator_fee_prorata": 168.43,
          "policy_administrator_fee_prorata_vat": 21.97,
          "sasria_type": "sas1",
          "sasria_calculation": "calculated",
          "sasria_shortfall_disabled": "No",
          "extract_run_date": "2022-02-08T23:12:04.88",
          "insurer_agent_number": "123",
          "insurer_product_type": null,
          "insurer_premium_class_code": null,
          "insurer_premium_class_description": null,
          "insurer_lob_code": null,
          "insurer_lob_description": null,
          "payment_frequency": "Monthly",
          "broker_code": "111222333",
          "currency": "ZAR",
          "brokerage_branch_address_line_1": "",
          "brokerage_branch_address_line_2": "",
          "brokerage_branch_address_line_3": "",
          "brokerage_branch_address_line_4": "",
          "brokerage_branch_address_suburb": "",
          "brokerage_branch_address_city": "",
          "brokerage_branch_address_province": "",
          "brokerage_branch_address_country": "",
          "brokerage_branch_address_postal_code": "",
          "insurer_branch_code": "SA",
          "insurer_broker_code": "",
          "insurer_product_typecode": "",
          "policy_term": "Monthly",
          "policy_coinsurance_indicator": "No",
          "policy_coinsurance_percentage": 0,
          "policy_reinsurance_indicator": "No",
          "policy_vap_indicator": "No",
          "rb_calendar_date": "2022-02-08T23:30:00.263",
          "rb_batch_date": "2022-02-08"
        }
      ],
      "item",
      [
        {
          "policy_unique_reference": "pol1",
          "item_unique_reference": "itm1",
          "item_parent_item_unique_reference": "",
          "item_type": "Cover",
          "item_parent_section": "temp",
          "item_subsection_extension": "",
          "policy_revision_no": 4,
          "policy_endorsement_no": 0,
          "item_description": "demo stuff",
          "item_asset_no": "1112221",
          "item_risk_address_line_1": "122 my street",
          "item_risk_address_line_2": "",
          "item_risk_address_line_3": "",
          "item_risk_address_line_4": "",
          "item_risk_address_suburb": "",
          "item_risk_address_city": "",
          "item_risk_address_province": "",
          "item_risk_address_country": "My country",
          "item_risk_address_postal_code": "1112",
          "item_risk_address_latitude": "",
          "item_risk_address_longitude": "",
          "item_premium": 1,
          "item_premium_vat": 0.13,
          "rated_premium": 1,
          "rated_premium_vat": 1,
          "vat_rate": 15,
          "item_premium_prorata": 1,
          "item_premium_prorata_vat": 0.13,
          "item_premium_discount_loading": 0,
          "item_premium_discount_loading_vat": 0,
          "item_premium_discount_loading_prorata": 0,
          "item_premium_discountloading_prorata_vat": 0,
          "item_commission": 0.2,
          "item_commission_vat": 0.03,
          "item_commission_prorata": 0.2,
          "item_commission_prorata_vat": 0.03,
          "item_commission_percentage": 20,
          "item_sum_insured": 5000000,
          "item_rate": 0,
          "item_removed_date": null,
          "item_original_start_date": "2021-11-01",
          "item_lastamended_date": "2021-11-01",
          "item_rating_date": "2021-10-08",
          "item_fee": 0,
          "item_feevat": 0,
          "item_fee_prorata": 0,
          "item_fee_prorata_vat": 0,
          "item_is_latest_endorsement": "Yes",
          "extract_rundate": "2022-02-08T23:12:04.88",
          "item_rate_percentage_based": "Yes",
          "item_commercial_breakdown": "",
          "insurer_premium_class_code": "",
          "insurer_premium_class_description": "",
          "insurer_lob_code": "",
          "insurerlob_description": "",
          "item_insurer_neighbourhood_code": "0",
          "item_risk_cancellation_reason": null,
          "item_coinsurance_indicator": "No",
          "item_coinsurance_percentage": 0,
          "item_status": "Active"
        },
      "item_excess",
      [
        {
          "policy_unique_reference": "pol1",
          "item_unique_reference": "itm1",
          "item_parent_item_unique_reference": "",
          "item_type": "Cover",
          "item_parent_section": "temp",
          "item_subsection_extension": "",
          "policy_revision_no": 4,
          "policy_endorsement_no": 0,
          "item_description": "temp",
          "item_asset_no": "111222",
          "item_risk_address_line_1": "",
          "item_risk_address_line_2": "",
          "item_risk_address_line_3": "",
          "item_risk_address_line_4": "",
          "item_risk_address_suburb": "",
          "item_risk_address_city": "",
          "item_risk_address_province": "",
          "item_risk_address_country": "My country",
          "item_risk_address_postal_code": "1112",
          "item_risk_address_latitude": "",
          "item_risk_address_longitude": "",
          "item_premium": 1,
          "item_premium_vat": 0.13,
          "rated_premium": 1,
          "rated_premium_vat": 1,
          "vat_rate": 15,
          "item_premium_prorata": 1,
          "item_premium_prorata_vat": 0.13,
          "item_premium_discount_loading": 0,
          "item_premium_discount_loading_vat": 0,
          "item_premium_discount_loading_prorata": 0,
          "item_premium_discountloading_prorata_vat": 0,
          "item_commission": 0.2,
          "item_commission_vat": 0.03,
          "item_commission_prorata": 0.2,
          "item_commission_prorata_vat": 0.03,
          "item_commission_percentage": 20,
          "item_sum_insured": 5000000,
          "item_rate": 0,
          "item_removed_date": null,
          "item_original_start_date": "2021-11-01",
          "item_lastamended_date": "2021-11-01",
          "item_rating_date": "2021-10-08",
          "item_fee": 0,
          "item_feevat": 0,
          "item_fee_prorata": 0,
          "item_fee_prorata_vat": 0,
          "item_is_latest_endorsement": "Yes",
          "extract_rundate": "2022-02-08T23:12:04.88",
          "item_rate_percentage_based": "Yes",
          "item_commercial_breakdown": "",
          "insurer_premium_class_code": "",
          "insurer_premium_class_description": "",
          "insurer_lob_code": "",
          "insurerlob_description": "",
          "item_insurer_neighbourhood_code": "0",
          "item_risk_cancellation_reason": null,
          "item_coinsurance_indicator": "No",
          "item_coinsurance_percentage": 0,
          "item_status": "Active"
        }],
      "item_extra",
      [
        {
          "item_unique_reference": "itm1",
          "policy_revision_no": 4,
          "policy_endorsement_no": 0,
          "extra_description": "Extra Items Demo",
          "extra_sum_insured": 12223,
          "extra_premium": 0,
          "extra_type": ""
        }
      ]
    ]
  ]
]]
```

The structure that I need should look like this:

```
{
   "policy": {
                … (current policy data), 
      "items": [
         {
            "items_excess": [
               {}
            ],
            "item_extra": [
               {}
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

I have added the create table and data inserts as well as the current cursor here : https://www.dropbox.com/sh/j1ay310s48s27xj/AABzx6lw8_SP82m0SGp7KCeja?dl=0

Just as a bit of background, the reason for going this route is that I get a request with a unique number which then gets populated into the cursor (the policy_temp table). I use this as there can be more than one number that gets sent through and I must retrieve all the data for the numbers. The only table that should return only one row of data per unique number (If the number exists in the table) is the ifs_isr_policy table. The rest would return anything from one to 50 rows of data, hence the cursor. I hope my madness makes sense.

Comment: Please edit your post and add create tables scripts, sample datas

Comment: Hi @Philippe Apologies for the late response. I edited the original question and added a link with the files etc.

Comment: The temp select you display in your query does not match with your dropbox files see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=84bccd297e755916a3b0389212db173b). Can you update directly the dbfiddle to make it running and then give us the access to the corresponding url ?

Comment: Hi please see the changes as requested. [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=7c853372eba8bdf9e1df4539ce81b9f6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
SELECT jsonb_build_object
           ( 'policy'
           , policy::jsonb
             || jsonb_build_object
                   ( 'items'
                   , array[jsonb_build_object
                              ( 'item_excess'
                              , item_excess::jsonb
                              , 'item_extra'
                              , item_extra::jsonb
                              )
                          ]
                   )
           ) AS tst
  FROM itg.digiflow_test
```

see the test result in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=26c335580c7ba43fba36e13d2cc7f40d)

Comment: This actually works exactly the way I need it, thank you so much, I really appreciate!